# usage of CP-SAT to forecast 3 Milions of boolean variables

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

Dears,
I want to understand if I using not properly the CP-SAT algorithm. Basically my code automatically creates a model reading a csv with a dataset. My code creates  model.NewBoolVar() for each record of the dataset multiplied for the number of possible decisions to be taken by the optimization problem... 
For example if I have a dataset with 1 Milion of records and I have to decide between 3 options, the model will contains 3 Milions of boolean variables. The combination of the 3 Milions of booleans is the solution to my optimizzation problem.

Currently after 100K variables the program is becoming unstable and python crashes. Do you think that I'm trying to use CP-SAT not properly? Do you have experience with this kind of volumes?

Thank you very much.
Cheers

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: 4gb...my program uses about 3gb

Comment: Since you are asking about RAM i'm assuming my case is not so un usual :) am I right?

Comment: What do you mean for solve for eahc solution and compare? Could you just make a little example?

Comment: forget it, I misunderstood. Are you sure you can't divide more your problem, you could also try BOP if you only have booleans

Answer (score 0):

You are aware that this is an NP problem. 
Thus potentially, you are creating a search tree of size 2^3000000000.

Comment: Yes I know...basically to give you the idea i'm trying to solve the equivalent of the knapsack problem with milions of items asking to the solver for each item to tell me if the item must be included or not. I know that i can try to make clusters of similar items and try just to find the number of items that must fall into each cluster. But for what i have to do it will be great to get a decision for each item. I understand from your words that there is no way to do it for a big number of items even if CP-SAT is incredible.

Comment: Actually, you can try to solve it as a LP problem, solve the simplex, and then round up or down fractional values. If the rounding is optimistic or pessimistic on 10k variables, 10k over 3M is in fact a good ratio.

Comment: Hi Laurent, sorry but i'm not getting your solution. Could you elaborate more? Thank you in advance

Comment: Solve this as a LP, sort variables by fractional values, and round the closest to 1 to 1, while maintaining feasability.